# App settings in iPhone Settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been reading and exploring around adding settings for custom apps in the iPhone settings page. 
And there is a question that is arising in my mind that, can we point an XIB / UIStoryboard-viewController which is designed by us into the root.plist.

This can help in displaying custom design and handling things differently as required.

For example, if custom app uses the passcode protection then we will need to save the passcode into the keychain and that will require additional logic to be written.

Cheers,
Kunjal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use custom UIViewControllers in the iOS settings page for your app. When using the Settings.bundle the preferences are stored in NSUserDefaults which does not integrate with the keychain. So you will need to include the settings view for the passcode in the app itself.

Comment: I thought so... Thanks for confirming Phix. I think apple must be using some private API's to do the same stuff in the settings app.